# Moving a sprite with touches began, casting and parameters in obj - c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I've been reading a book on the cocos2d framework for ios5 for a few days and have developed a small game that the book walks you through. To control the sprite in this game you use the accelerometer:

```
-(void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration
{

    float deceleration = 0.4f;
    float sensitivity = 6.0f;
    float maxVelocity = 100;

    // adjust velocity based on current accelerometer acceleration
    playerVelocity.x = playerVelocity.x * deceleration + acceleration.x * sensitivity;

    // we must limit the maximum velocity of the player sprite, in both directions (positive & negative values)
    if (playerVelocity.x > maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.x = maxVelocity;
    }
    else if (playerVelocity.x < -maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.x = -maxVelocity;
    }

    // Alternatively, the above if/else if block can be rewritten using fminf and fmaxf more neatly like so:
    // playerVelocity.x = fmaxf(fminf(playerVelocity.x, maxVelocity), -maxVelocity);
}
```

Now I'm wondering if I can change this code to allow the sprite to still accelerate/decelerate along the x axis, but to use touch input rather than the accelerometer, and to go faster the longer the touch is held down for? So a touch to the right would move the sprite to that spot slowly, if the touch is released, it stops moving to that spot. The longer a touch is held down, the faster the sprite moves.

is there anything in the framework to allow me to implement a rotation mechanism that allows my sprite to rotate to the position that the touch was in, so it looks like its facing the point thats been touched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, afaik theres no method that will determine the angle to the touch and then rotate the sprite accordingly, but if you have the x and y coordinates of the sprite and the touch you can calculate it yourself fairly easily.

```
CGPoint spriteCenter; // this should represent the center position of the sprite
CGPoint touchPoint; //location of touch

float distanceX = touchPoint.x - spriteCenter.x;
float distanceY = touchPoint.y - spriteCenter.y;

float angle = atan2f(distanceY,distanceX); // returns angle in radians

// do whatever you need to with the angle
```

Once you have the angle you can set the rotation of the sprite.